# Is it possible to use a conditional construct to enable an attribute in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, razorengine

Consider the following Razor component.

```
@code
{
    private bool isIndex = true;
}


@if (isIndex)
{
    <NavLink href="" Match=NavLinkMatch.All>
        Index
    </NavLink>
}
else
{
    <NavLink href="Other">
        Other
    </NavLink>
}
```

Is it possible to use a conditional construct to enable `Match=NavLinkMatch.All` that renders the same output as above?

```
<NavLink href=@(isIndex? string.Empty:"Other")>
    @(isIndex? "Index": "Other")
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a conditional construct to enable `Match=NavLinkMatch.All`

It is an enum with two values.

You can just use   `Match="@(IsIndex ?  NavLinkMatch.All : NavLink.Prefix)"`
`Prefix` is the default so you don't see it much.

But more in general: no, you can only apply C# logic to the *values* of attributes. Unless you want to drop down to BuildRenderTree code.

Comment: I guess NavLink is just an example. In my opinion OP is not looking for a solution for NavLink but a generic solution for any case. For example, do you want to set `MaxLeng` only if a flag is true. [By default MacLebg is Unlimited](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Comment: Yes, I picked up on the specific case in the question. I just quoted it.

Comment: Now is fine for me. It's a pity this is a not supported feature.

Comment: Yes, something like how disabled=false works. But it would be hard to come up with something that would work for all attributes.

Comment: Henk, what about splatting attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022065/842935

Comment: Yes, with splatting you could make something work for `<MyNavLinkWrapper>` but I don't see a general solution.